# BottomNavigationView enable click disable check

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-menu, bottomnavigationview

I'm using a BottomNavigationView with 5 items, 4 Fragments and 1 Activity as in the image below

[image]

When any fragment is clicked I want it to act normally getting `clicked` and `checked`, but when the "+" item is clicked I'm opening an Activity but I don't want it to be `checked`, so I want it to be `clickable` so it can open the Activity, but I don't want to be `checked`, because when the user return back from the activity will see it selected even though it's the wrong selected item.
How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.home_nav_menu:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.inbox_nav_menu:
            fragment = new InboxFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.add_nav_menu:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.history_nav_menu:
            fragment = new HistoryFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.profile_nav_menu:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            break;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_place_holder, fragment).commit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post your code here , show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @Quicklearner I've the BottomNavigationView working normally without any problem, but I can't find any method to disable it from gaining focus or getting checked, so I don't have a code trying to disable it

Comment: i understand can you just add your code , so that we can see it and make changes in it

Comment: @Quicklearner Done

Comment: inside  case R.id.add_nav_menu:  menuItem.setCheckable(false);

Comment: @Manivasagam that one would set all the items to be not checked, but I want the selected item to remain selected when the "+" button is selected, so returning false solved it

Comment: Check my ansewer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seeing at the source code of the listener for the bottom navigation, you just need to return false when you don't want to display item as selected.

```
 /**
     * Listener for handling selection events on bottom navigation items.
     */
    public interface OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        /**
         * Called when an item in the bottom navigation menu is selected.
         *
         * @param item The selected item
         *
         * @return true to display the item as the selected item and false if the item should not
         *         be selected. Consider setting non-selectable items as disabled preemptively to
         *         make them appear non-interactive.
         */
        boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item);
    }
```

So you simply return false in your `case R.id.add_nav_menu:` and it will work.

Comment: That was so simple and nice, Thank you very much

Comment: see @YousefGamal if you post code with question , u will get the answer quickly :)

Comment: @Quicklearner yes that's something I just learned thanks to you ^_^

Answer (score 9):

User [`MenuItem#setCheckable(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setCheckable(boolean)) API in order to play with menu item's checkable state.

```
    MenuItem menuItem = navigation.getMenu().getItem(1);
    menuItem.setCheckable(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
int id = menuItem.getItemId();
Fragment fragment = null;
switch (id) {
    case R.id.home_nav_menu:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.inbox_nav_menu:
        fragment = new InboxFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.add_nav_menu:
  menuItem.setCheckable(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.history_nav_menu:
        fragment = new HistoryFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.profile_nav_menu:
        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        break;
}
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_place_holder, fragment).commit();
return true;
}
```